# Can't print line breaks with Rails and Wicked PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

My original text

```
test\r\n\r\ntest\r\n\r\ntest
```

View:

```
p = @property.data
```

Result in PDF

```
test test test
```

I need instead:

```
test

test

test
```

Comment: Isn't Wicked PDF using a HTML view? Wouldn't changing `\r\n` to `<br />` work?

Comment: This is user input, they have a freehand text form

Comment: Yes, so just translate linebreaks to <br /> before printing it to the HTML View you created for Wicked PDF.

Comment: Rails has a [`simple_format`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper for this kind of conversion. Or wrap the text in a `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [simple_format](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format) to convert line breaks to html new line tags. This works well with pdf too.

```
<%= simple_format p %>
```

***Note:*** If you are using rich text editor (such as [trix_editor](https://github.com/maclover7/trix)) `.html_safe` will work with line breaks. But in this case, `.html_safe` doesn't work in PDFs.